# Vagrant define path to website dir

Tags: vagrant

First, sorry for stupid question, because I'm pretty new in Vagrant and Linux.

### I'm trying to separate Vagrantfile and website project directory.

So I have next directories structure:

```
D:\VAGRANT    
    machines\domain.com
        Vagrantfile
        install.sh    
    domains\domain.com
        app\code.php
        web\index.php
```

I want to run Vagrant from dir D:\VAGRANT\machines\domain.com and get virtual machine with D:\VAGRANT\domains\domain.com as HOME and D:\VAGRANT\domains\domain.com\web as PUBLICK_HTML dir.
How can I do that?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another [sync folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/) so you can add in your Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.synced_folder "D:\\VAGRANT\\domains\\domain.com\\web", "<path where you deploy files in the vm>"
```

note : I am not using windows so not exactly sure how the path should be set in the file try with `\\` or forward slash `D:/VAGRANT/....`

Comment: Ah! Cool idea. Why I didn't think about that? Thank you!